# Is there an alternative way of changing the audio output device using web audio api?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Assume that I have access to the installed audio output devices and I have the labels and deviceId.Then I need to allow user change the output device using the selected device id.The only solution I got is by using setSinkId() method which found in audio element.But I want do solve this without using audio element only by using web audio api.Any suggestions plz.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently no better way to do this.

There is a long standing issue on the Web Audio API repository about adding that functionality.

https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api-v2/issues/10